# Does OCSP stapling increase performance for websites behind CloudFlare?

Tags: nginx, ssl, cloudflare

Should a website trying to increase performance that uses the CloudFlare CDN (or any CDN really) who [already do OCSP stapling](https://blog.cloudflare.com/ocsp-stapling-how-cloudflare-just-made-ssl-30/) configure [OCSP stapling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCSP_stapling) on their instance of [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_stapling) if "[Full SSL](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-mean-)" setting on CloudFlare is used?

In this setup when a browser requests a page from a CloudFlare protected/cached site they connect to CloudFlare using TLS, who then connects to the source web server using TLS to retrieve the freshly generated page. This means two sets of SSL negotiation are done, increasing the time required to retrieve the page. As an aside, HTTP/2 means the connection is only typically done once per website, regardless of the number of resources to download.

If CloudFlare checks the CRL for the source web server certificate I imagine OCSP stapling could reduce the checks required, and therefore the SSL setup time. However I'm not an expert in this area so I'd appreciate thoughts on this.

Some information from CloudFlare regarding whether it is helpful (which suggests it won't help performance)

*Thanks for your question. At this time we don't do revocation checking on the certificates served by origin. We may at some point, however, so would suggest stapling OCSP if using a publicly trusted certificate (and not much difficulty).*

Comment: I think you mean HTTP/2 not SSL 2. Even with HTTP/1.1 which needs several parallel connections to handle many resources, SSL/TLS should use 'abbreviated' handshake, aka session resumption or session sharing, which reduces the extra delay and cost but does not entirely eliminate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reiterate, the official response from CloudFlare is

*At this time we don't do revocation checking on the certificates served by origin. We may at some point, however, so would suggest stapling OCSP if using a publicly trusted certificate (and not much difficulty).*

To verify this I did a test run with stapling both off and on, the results are below. My methodology was to run five webpagetest.org tests with the setting on and off, take the median run, and average those. I ran the tests twice from each location with the setting both on and off.

The result is that stapling is 2.5% faster, but I suspect the margin of error means there's no significant difference.

[image]